# Proof of normalising the Dirac spinors

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, normalization

I was reading through my particle physics textbook and saw a property of the Dirac spinors that I did not understand. The spinor is defined by $u^s(p)=\sqrt{\frac{E+m}{2m}} \begin{bmatrix}\phi^s \\ \frac{\sigma p}{E+m}\phi^s \end{bmatrix}$. The normalisation of this means that the scalar invariant $\bar{\phi}\phi$ (where the conjugate spinor has its usual meaning) means the $\bar{u^s}(p)u^{s'}(p)=\delta_{s s'}$.

What I don't understand is how the normalisation yields a Kronecker delta? I have been trying to work through the maths to prove this but I end up with a 2x2 matrix and I don't know where to go from there?

Comment: what is the relation of the $s$ and $s'$ labels to the $a$ and $b$ labels?  Are they supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Its the two Weyl eigen-spinors $\phi^s$, that are mutually orthogonal that give the Kronecker delta.